# Style dentro de Vue.component

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

A pergunta é bem simples: Consigo inserir estilo CSS/SCSS dentro de um **Vue.component()**, para ficar dentro do escopo do componente?

**Algo do tipo**

```
const Color = Vue.component('Color', {
    props: ['row'],
    template: '<div class="badge-color" :style="{backgroundColor: this.row.color}"></div>'

    //parte abaixo é sugestiva, apenas para ilustrar o exemplo
    style:{'.badge-color':'width:100%'}
})
```

O cenário acima é um "mini" componente dentro de outro componente, apenas para organização. Não quero criar um arquivo .vue separado para isso, pois é algo muito simples - e necessário, devido a utilização do dataTable Vuejs.

Comment: Por nada, respondi a pergunta para ficar mais organizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é possível fora de [single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), pois a instância de componentes no modo tradicional não fornece a opção de estilo `CSS` nativo, mas a questão é, deveria fornecer?

Creio que não pois isso engloba a divisão de tarefas entre as linguagens, a propósito esse tema está sendo veemente discutido, [entenda](http://www.didoo.net/2017/10/let-there-be-peace-on-css/).

Então tal feito (por enquanto) só poderá ser feito por meio de de bibliotecas ou usando :style individualmente no qual é possível encapsular um objeto `CSS` para cada componente.

Comment: Isso respondeu minha duvida, Felipe. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

**Resposta atualizada:**

Se eu entendi corretamente, uma maneira de resolver, é você criar o componente *Color* dentro do componente "pai", ou seja, para **não** criar um novo arquivo/componente separado no caso do componente *Color*. Na *tag style* você coloca as classes normalmente, como se fossem para o componente "Pai", porém elas estão sendo utilizadas exclusivamente no componente "Filho", exemplo:

**Componente "Pai"**

```
<template lang="pug"> 
  div
    color(:row="{ color: 'red' }")
</template>
<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'

  Vue.component('color', {
    props: ['row'],
    template: '<div class="badge-color" :style="{backgroundColor: this.row.color}"><p>teste</p></div>'
  })
</script>

<style lang="stylus">    
  .badge-color
    width 100%
</style>
```

Outra maneira de realizar, é colocar de forma Global em seu arquivo `main.js` ou outro arquivo de configuração, exemplo:

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '@/App'
import router from '@/router'
import store from '@/store'

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
}) 

Vue.component('color', {
  props: ['row'],
  template: '<div class="badge-color" :style="{backgroundColor: this.row.color}"><p>teste</p></div>'
})
```

E no seu componente que você quer utilizar o componente *Color*, você chama ele normalmente, e insere da mesma forma o css em sua *tag style*, exemplo:

**Componente "Pai" utilizando o componente Color de forma global**

```
<template lang="pug"> 
  div
    color(:row="{ color: 'red' }")
</template>
<script>      
// código
</script>

<style lang="stylus">    
  .badge-color
    width 100%
</style>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, amigo, mas se reparar no final da pergunta, eu digo que não quero criar um novo arquivo/componente separado, por se tratar de uma implantação minúscula.

Comment: Então, mas você quer colocar o componente Color dentro de outro componente, correto? A implementação acima é referente ao novo componente, onde dentro dele possui o componente Color. Você pode colocar também o Vue.component('color'... em seu main.js para deixá-lo de forma global, farei a alteração da resposta em instantes para ver se é algo que lhe ajuda.